# Do not send textarea to BCC email CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form, contact-form-7

We run a site that finds customers for psychologists. A new EU law does not allow us to read sensitive information. We are currently using CF7 for the contact form, and both we and the psychologist need to receive an email upon answer. We however do not need the message field, which is the one that is not allowed.

Is it possible to send all CF7 content to the main email, but everything but the message/textarea to the bcc email?

Comment: you will need to send 2 emails.

Comment: @rtfm is right, you need to use the 2nd email option in your cf7 form settings and configure it so that it does not have a the message field in its body.

Comment: Yeah that was the fix I did myself as well. But since we have hundreds of forms this is quite a lot of work. I was wondering if there was a simple PHP fix. Thank you two anyway, I will leave it open in case someone else finds a solution or needs it.